# Obtaining input values in table with loop using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I have a table that adds and removes rows with buttons and within each cell I have an input which I'm trying to pull out and form a JSON string.

I'm pretty sure I'm nearly there however i've been going slightly crazy with getting values out of the input fields and into the variables to print the JSON.

See the note in the comments by my problem string.

Anyhelp with what selector I need to be using to pull data out the input. A table row looks like this:

```
     <tr class="">
                            <td><select class="id" ><option></option><option></option><option></option></select></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subtask_assignee[]" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="subtask_summary[]" /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="col3[]" value="" /></td>
                            <td><button class="remove">Remove</button>
                        </tr>
```

This is how far I've got:

```
         var table = document.getElementById('myTable');
         var rowLength = table.rows.length;
         console.log("rows"+rowLength);
         for(var i=2; i<rowLength; i+=1){
            //check if row exists
            if (table.rows[i]) {
              var row = table.rows[i];
              console.log("outer"+i);

            var cellLength = row.cells.length;
            for(var y=0; y<cellLength-1; y+=1){
                var subtask = row.cells[y];
                    console.log("inner" + y);

                subtask.fields = {};
             // THIS SELECTOR TO GET THE VALUE IN THE INPUTS IN THE ROW BELOW IS I BELIEVE THE PROBLEM. IT IS RETURNING BLANK IN THE ALERT WHICH I HAVE PUT INTO TEST. 
                subtask.fields = {};
                subtask.fields.parent = $('#dynatable > tbody  > tr > td').val();
                subtask.fields.assignee = $('#dynatable > tbody  > tr > td').val();
                subtask.fields.assignee = {};
                subtask.fields.assignee.col4 = $('#dynatable > tbody  > tr > td').val();

                alert(subtask.fields.parent);
            }

              alert(JSON.stringify(subtask));
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `var JSON = JSON.stringify( $('table input').map(function() {return this.value}).get() )`

Comment: Are you trying to get the whole table in one object?

Comment: Yes in a long way round. I have updated the code to highlight where I am finding the problem. I am struggling to pass the value in the field to the variable. I think this is right... but at the same time wrong. $('#dynatable > tbody  > tr > td').val();

Answer (score 0):

Use below JSON.stringify()

```
var JSONDATA = JSON.stringify( $('table input').map(function() {return this.value}).get() )
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: I am managing to create the JSON string, just not able to get the selector correct for the input. I have added a comment by the problem selector. Thanks